# How to index the value in array?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to debug. My best guess is the array indexing is a problem.

```vb
Public Function CFR(df(), x As Double, t As Integer) As Double
    Dim i, y As Integer
    Dim discount()
    Dim nom, denom As Double
    ReDim discount(t) As Double

    y = 1
    For i = UBound(df, 1) + 1 To t
        discount(i) = df(UBound(df, 1)) * (x ^ y)
        y = y + 1
    Next I

    nom = (1 - df(UBound(df)) * x ^ (t - UBound(df)))
    denom = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(df) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(discount)
    CFR = nom / denim
End Function
```

Comment: what problem/error are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

you should really use `Option Explicit`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CFR(df(), x As Double, t As Integer) As Double
    Dim i As Long, y As Integer
    Dim discount() As Double
    Dim nom, denom As Double
    ReDim discount(t) As Double

    y = 1
    For i = UBound(df, 1) + 1 To t
        discount(i) = df(UBound(df, 1)) * (x ^ y)
        y = y + 1
    Next i

    nom = (1 - df(UBound(df)) * x ^ (t - UBound(df)))
    denom = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(df) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(discount)

    CFR = nom / denom

End Function
```

The issues were

1)  `denim` instad of `denom`

which the use of `Option Explicit` would found you out immediatley

2) `Dim discount()` 
Since VBA assumes implicit `Variant` type for all not explicitly declared variables, and that makes it collidw with subsequent `ReDim discount(t) As Double` since the Redim() statement cannot change the type of the array

3) point 2 explanation is relevant for a minor issue (not blocking the code in this case):

```
Dim i, y As Integer
```

is actually read as:

```
Dim i As Variant, y As Integer
```

If you want `i` to be of `integer` type you have to code:

```
Dim i As Integer, y As Integer
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just found that the range object can not be indexed.
Eg. 
''' array = range("a1:a10") 
then I want to index "a2" value, so I code
''' array(2)

It does not work, but now I change it.